# How to stream different webcams in 2 different pages with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, while-loop, stream, camera

I'm trying to create a Flask application that would allow the user to stream 2 different webcams, but in different pages.
I managed to make one of the cameras work with the code below, however, once the streaming starts, it gets forever stuck in the "while true" loop in the "gen_frames()" function, making it impossible for the user to return to the index page and choose another camera to stream.
I tried using threading, but didn't actually know what I was doing, so gave up on that idea.
Any thoughts on how to make the user able to return to the main Flask page, interrupting the while true loop?

```
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

global camera

def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/Camera<int:x>')
def camera(x):
    global camera
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(x-1)
    return render_template('cameras.html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

"index.html" has the small html code with hyperlinks to the other pages, and "cameras.html" has the html code with the and the streaming itself and the return hyperlink to go back to the index page. I really need a way to make this work, but nothing I tried so far helped me.

Comment: you should call it asynchronously, check this out: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/async-await/

Comment: @teal33t i took a look at it, but i'm not sure on how i could make it work. you have any examples? i'm having trouble making the async work in first place